# how to make a space between fluid div and fixed div

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have this code which is making a fluid div next to a fixed div.

how can I make a margin of 10px between them?

```
<div id="wrapper" style="width: 100%">
<div id="left" style="background-color: Blue; height: 100px; float: right; width: 200px;margin-left:10px;"></div>
<div id="right" style="background-color: #5a71e5; height: 100px; margin-right: 200px;"></div>
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3P9XN/1/

Comment: in the future try to separate the html and css, makes it much more readable

Comment: Here's a [jsFiddle with the styles in the CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/roryokane/UwAcn/) instead of in the HTML.

Comment: Warning: the `<div id="left">` is actually displayed on the right, with `float: right`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either make the `width` of the right div less, or the `margin-right` of the left div more. In the example below, I increased the `margin-right`.

```
<div id="wrapper" style="width: 100%">
<div id="left" style="background-color: Blue; height: 100px; float: right; width: 200px;margin-left:10px;"></div>
<div id="right" style="background-color: #5a71e5; height: 100px; margin-right: 210px;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
#right {
    background-color: #5a71e5;
    height: 100px; 
    margin-right: 220px;
}
```